# Singular chain complex for integration - pinching on boundary

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, simplex

Singular chain complex, as far as topology are concerned, is just continuous map from standard simplex, and the choice of using simplex over other shape is immaterial. But for integration on manifold, you need the map to be $C^{\infty}$. This is what bugged me, because using $C^{\infty}$ map from an $n$-simplex, you can "pinch" the boundary at most $n+1$ times. So the image of a 2-simplex can never be, say, a rectangle, or a Koch snowflake. I suppose there should be a better definition of chain for the purpose of integration that does not depend arbitrarily on the shape you started with, but I cannot find it. Can someone explain this to me, or point me to a source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to integrate on in a manifold is a submanifold. IIRC the notion of a smooth simplex really only comes up in proving de Rham's theorem: but note you can approximate a rectangle, for instance, as the sum of two smooth 2-simplices, and the Koch snowflake can't possibly be a smooth chain.

Comment: Can you clarify what sense of "submanifold" is this? Also, about "Koch snowflake can't possibly be a smooth chain": isn't this part of the problem? It make perfect sense to integrate over the Koch snowflake, yet it is not a smooth chain you can integrate over.

Comment: It makes sense to integrate over the Koch snowflake, but only in the continuous setting. So, if that's important to you, then you shouldn't work in the smooth setting. Let's say I mean (smoothly) immersed submanifold, although one can do something useful with any smooth map-it's just that immersions are the most general case in which it's sensible to identify a manifold mapping in with its image.

Comment: @Desperado a) Given any embedded submanifold $N \subset M$ of dimension $k$ and a compactly supported $k$-form on $M$, you can pull this form back and integrate it on $N$. One can do things more generally, too, as Kevin mentions above. b) In what way is it a problem that you can't integrate a 1-form on a Koch snowflake?

Comment: I think the failure to integrate on the Koch snowflake just means that the concept of integration on manifold is not quite a true generalization of integration on Euclidean space. That would be fine if there is some sort of technical issue one would encountered if one try, but here it just seems like the problem arise because people decide to arbitrarily pick a simplex, instead of something with nowhere differentiable boundary, which would make it more general. If we instead integrate over submanifold with boundary, once again it is why the half-space is the model for boundary.

Comment: I think you haven't made quite clear exactly what it is you want to integrate. If it's differential forms, then you can't integrate over the Koch snowflake in Euclidean space either. If it's measurable functions, then a measure on your manifold induces one on an embedded snowflake and again there's no problem. So I'm not sure what you think you can do in Euclidean space but not on a manifold.